# How to post form then handle jsonp response?

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

Im very confused on how to handle this. I've read many posts on this forum about using jQuery.ajax and jQuery.post to "post" forms as JSON and JSONP. However Im using a webservice that accepts a regular form POST and returns a JSONP response.  How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

JSONP as defined, e.g., at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) only supports get requests. So there is no possibility to use POST requests as a technique to retrieve cross domain JSON data using JSONP.

Comment: What about POSTing to an Iframe  and parse the source of the Iframe? Worse case it looks  like the webservice accepts GET requests too  so I guess I can use $.getJSON and serialize.. but I have to be mindful of the data limit

Comment: @htmlr The problem with the iframe (as with most other elements) is the same origin policy for JavaScript, which basically prevents you from accessing resources of domains different to the current one. The approach using JSONP is one (rare) exception from this. The other one are [CORS-enabled](http://enable-cors.org/) resources.

Comment: Thanks, just got the X-domain error when trying to parse the Iframe src `<form action="http://test.website.com/web.asp?action=reaaccount&method=SAVEREACONN&apikey=%2B3CbnLtr2%2B8%3D&callback=?" method="post" target="myframe" >`
   
    <input type="submit" value="POST" />
</form>
<iframe id="myframe" onload="parseJSON(this.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])" ></iframe>